# Condition for that convex cone contains a positive vector

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And let $C$ be the convex cone generated by these $n$ vectors, i.e., $C=\{ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i \mid \lambda_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i=1,...,n\}$. I would like to know any literature, which has the condition on $a_i$ such that $C \cap \mathbb{R}^n_{+} \setminus \{0\} \neq \emptyset$.

I'm looking at something like Farkas' lemma. It's interesting but I want to know some conditions on the entries of $a_i$ like how many of them are positive, negative, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is worth saying in full what Farkas' lemma implies for this scenario: $C$ will fail to contain positive vectors if and only if for each positive vector $b$, there exists a vector $y$ for which $A^Ty \geq 0$ and $b^Ty < 0$ (where $A$ has columns $a_1,\dots,a_n$)

Comment: The above formulation lends itself to interpretation via an optimization problem: $C$ fails to contain positive vectors iff
$$
\max_{b \geq 0} \min_{y: A^Ty \geq 0} b^Ty < 0. 
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will notice it.

Comment: Actually, the maximization is not quite right. It should be something like
$$
\max_{b \geq 0: 1^Tb = 1} \min_{y: A^Ty \geq 0} b^T
$$